# Spring ResourceBunddleMessageSource is not taking default messages.properties file

Tags: java, spring, internationalization

I am using Spring ResourceBundleMessageSource for internationalization. In view form I am using `fmt:message` for form field labels. In validator when field values are not correct I have to reject the field with respective form field labels & error message. 
  e.g. `<fmt:message key"abc" /> <form:input name="xyz">`

Error message would be: "value for abc is incorrect".

In validator i have to say -

```
`errors.rejectValue("xyz", "error.message", new Object[] {getMessage("message.abc")})`
```

spring config:

```
<bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource"> 
 <property name="basename" value="MySource" /> 
</bean>
```

In `getMessage` I am using `MessageSourceAccesor` to read message from resource file.

My resource file name is `MySource.properties`, there are no other language specific files in my resource folder, also I am able to read the labels from this file in jsp view, but I am getting exception (`NoSuchMessage` for abc in locale en) when i tries to access it from validator.

The short question would be how to instruct spring resource to use default properties file (filename without suffix) to search the messages when language resource files are not provided?

Any pointer would be helpful to move ahead.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem. Upon checking the documentation for spring mvc, mine is release 4.1.1, **ResourceBundleMessageSource** has "***basenames***" as property instead of "***basename***"

```
private String[] basenames = new String[0];
```

Updating property name of ResourceBundleMessageSource bean configured in spring web app context, made it worked :D

```
<property name="basenames" value="messages"></property>
```

I can't post my screenshots yet, because i need 10 points, and I am a newbie here :D

Comment: No, it also has the `basename` property. `basenames` would be for a `String` array: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.1.1.RELEASE/javadoc-api/

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using Spring MVC ,

have you configured Spring Resource bundle in your application context file

**Example**

```
<beans:bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">       
        <beans:property name="basename" value="classpath:messages" />
        <beans:property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
</beans:bean>
```

This link explains it in detail with a demo
[Spring Resource bundle with ResourceBundleMessageSource example](http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-resource-bundle-with-resourcebundlemessagesource-example/)

Please rate the post , if this helps.

Comment: Yes, I am using spring MVC & following is my configuration - <beans:bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">       
        <beans:property name="basename" value="MySource" />
</beans:bean>     as i mentioned it works for view part issue is with validator.